# Stream GPS coordinates using D3 and Mapbox

Tags: gps, mapbox, mapping, d3, mapbox-gl

I’m currently working on a project to stream GeoJSON data using D3 and Mapbox. But, I wasn’t able to plot my data based on their types. Basically, I have three different types of GPS data, when using d3 to plot them in circles, I want to fill circles with different colors based on type of the GPS data. Below is part of my GeoJSON data:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "hour": 2.0,
            "min": 21.0,
            "type": 1.0
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -74.1964708,
                40.7105689
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "hour": 2.0,
            "min": 21.0,
            "type": 2.0
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -73.94199820000001,
                40.6963346
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "hour": 2.0,
            "min": 21.0,
            "type": 1.0
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -73.8975397,
                40.6398408
            ]
        }
    ]}}
```

Also, I attached a screenshot of my visualizations here:
[image]

Here is the function I used to create circles on the map:

```
async function createDots(data) {
    var colors = ['blue', 'green', 'yellow', '#59f3b8'];
    var container = map.getCanvasContainer();
    var svg = d3
      .select(container)
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", "100%")
      .attr("height", "2000")
      // Ensure d3 layer in front of map
      .style("position", "absolute")
      .style("z-index", 10);

    var circles = d3.select("svg")
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(data.features)
      circles
        .exit()
          .remove();
      circles
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
          .attr("r", 1.5)
          .style("opacity", 0.8)
          //.style("fill", colors[3]) // fill data.color?
          //.style("fill", function(d){ if (d.Fruit == "strawberry") {return colors(d.Year)} else if (d.Fruit == "grape") {return colors1(d.Year)} else {return colors2(d.Year)}})
          // data.features[0].properties.type
          .style("fill", function(data, i) {
              return colors[data.features[i].properties.type];
            })
        .merge(circles)
          .attr("cx", function(d) {
            return project(d.geometry.coordinates).x;
          })
          .attr("cy", function(d) {
            return project(d.geometry.coordinates).y;
          });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got my problem solved by checking this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17348538/17224444

Below is the correct code to fill colors based on "type" in my GeoJSON data, in the createDots() function, changed the original .style code to below version

```
              .style("fill", function(data, i) {
              return colors[data.properties.type];
            })
```